# Is there a way to Use Windows 2008 Backup to FTP

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to use windows backup in Windows 2008 to store to an external FTP server?

Answer (score 2):

Not by itself.  You can automate uploading the file to an FTP server by calling ftp.exe and giving it the -s switch with a file which includes the commands to upload the backup file.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Windows Backup does not have direct FTP support. Novell has a now inactive application/driver by the name of Netdrive which will connect to a FTP server and present a drive letter to that connection.

http://www.novell.com/documentation/oes/pdfdoc/netdrive/netdrive.pdf

The FTP drive letter can then be used as a backup location for Windows Backup.

Netdrive itself is a little bit hard to find on the Novell site and its licensing is not necessarily clear these days.